# SQL to return From/To dates with gaps

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a temp table that has data like this:
[image]

I need to come up with t-SQL that will show the dates in/out for the lot like this:
[image]

Since the lot went empty on 6/12/15, I need to show 2 separate rows to allow for the gap in the date range when the lot had no qty. I've tried using MIN and MAX but I can't seem to figure out how to allow for the time gap. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Thanks.

Comment: You probably need a running total for the quantity, and use that with any solution for gaps and islands problem

Comment: I have a running total on the qty -- it's called Run Bal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to divide the groups when the balanced has switched from zero.  So, you can define the groups by doing a cumulative count of the 0 running balances.  The value is actually more accurate if you do this in reverse order.

This provides a grouping, which you can use for aggregation:

```
select lot, min(trandate), max(trandate)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when runbal = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over
                 (partition by lot order by trandate desc) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by grp
order by min(trandate);
```